# SQL query on same duplicate tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Working with Access, I have the following table

```
ID  Root_ID  Level  Code
S1  S        10     ABC
S3  S        20     DFG
L4  L        10     FFF
L4  L        20     GGG
F2  F        10     ABC
```

What I'm looking for is: rows having the same code, on the same level but different Root_IDs.

I created a query with twice the same table T and an innner join on both the Level and the code. I tried this first before trying to identify the different Root_IDs but returned results were wrong...

Here for example, the result should be:

```
ID  Root_ID  Level  Code
S1  S        10     ABC
F2  F        10     ABC
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the code, level for which there are more than one unique root_ids in a subquery and then join it with table to get the complete rows.

```
select a.*
from your_table as a
inner join (
    select code, level
    from your_table
    group by code, level
    having count(distinct root_id) > 1
    ) as b on a.code = b.code
    and a.level = b.level
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t1.*
from your_table as t1
inner join (
    select code, level
    from your_table
    group by code, level
    having min(root_id) <> max(root_id)
    ) as t2 on t1.code = t2.code
    and t1.level = t2.level
```